# Images load fine directly, but not on the actual page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am having problems with my HTML image code. The first few images load, then the rest don't. They load when accessed directly, but not through the page.
See page here: http://swaba.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/cinderella/cinderella.html#tonights-the-night
(It's for a friend who's helping at a school play)
here is the image code I used:

```
<h1 class="sans">Lyrics</h1>
<br>
<a id="tonights-the-night">
<h3 class="semi-sans">Tonight's The Night</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="01.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="a-friend-like-you">
<h3 class="semi-sans">A Friend Like You</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="02.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="its-not-all-its-cracked-up-to-be">
<h3 class="semi-sans">It's Not All It's Cracked Up To Be</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="03.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="im-so-in-love-with-me">
<h3 class="semi-sans">I'm So In Love With Me</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="04.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="youre-going-to-the-ball">
<h3 class="semi-sans">You're Going To The Ball</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="05.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="theres-a-party-here-tonight">
<h3 class="semi-sans">There's A Party Here Tonight</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="06.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="a-ton-of-love">src="07.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="if-i-had-one-wish">
<h3 class="semi-sans">If I Had One Wish</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="08.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="your-feet-are-too-big">
<h3 class="semi-sans">Your Feet Are Too Big</h3></a> <img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="09.png" width="800"><br>
<img alt="Cinderella Lyrics" src="09-2.png" width="800"><br>
<a id="happy-ever-afters">
<h3 class="semi-sans">Happy Ever Afters</h3></a> <img alt=
"Cinderella Lyrics" src="10.png" width="800"><br>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: The images stop loading after the '03.png'

EDIT: The images load correctly in Firefox, just not on Chrome.

Comment: I opened your page and could see images upto 11.png. You sure? :)

Comment: It seems to work for me. Check your browser console for errors. And provide more information like what browser you are using.

Comment: I can't, I don't know what the problem is then

Comment: What browsers did you tried?

Comment: my guess is that the internet is taking time to load all the images. If u see the audios have started to load. so i guess the images on the bottom of the page has not loaded yet. take some time to see if more images loads.

Comment: Open developer tools and check disable cache then reload.

Comment: Can you try on some others. And are you seeing any error e.g 404 on Chrome console?

Comment: Got a picture of what I see here: [link](http://swaba.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/img/capture.png)

Comment: @chRyNaN, I know the dev options (F12), but I don't see 'Disable Cache'. I'm probably being dumb    EDIT: Found it

Comment: There is a lot of invalid HTML here if parsed using strict rules. Your img and br tags need to be closed (ie <img /> <br />). The effect of not closing  a tag is browser dependent and also the doctype (HTML 5, 4.01 Strict, etc...).

Comment: Unable to open the link :(

Comment: You have to click the gear option to bring up settings. That being said I replicated your problem and it seems to be with loading.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 Actually, I did close them but the HTML was hard to read, so i used Dirty Markup to make it easier. That must have done that :P

Comment: I give up with that link. Go here for the code: http://pastebin.com/FciRFKwa

Comment: @αƞjiβ No 404s on Chrome, but Firefox shows me the images

Comment: You should reduce the sizes of your files.  I took your first image which was 2.1mb (large for loading that many images) and was able to reduce it to 140k.  Go into photoshop, reduce the image width to 800px and save for web at a medium JPG setting.  Then reupload all of the images and try again

Comment: @ntgCleaner that helped, now I see up to 'Your Feet Are Too Big'. See [here](http://swaba.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/img/Capture2.PNG) Also, I have updated the code @ [code.txt](http://swaba.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/code.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

I needed to do the following to fix:

**• Lower the resolution of the images. At the time I was using the  tag's width feature to re-size, putting a lot of pressure on the browser.**

**• Set the height feature**

**• And, compress the images**

This all led to me being able to see the lyrics on my site!